# FireDAC Error al Editar

Tags: delphi, delphi-tokyo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al querer editar cualquier campo de mi tabla me aparece este error el cual no deja aplicar los cambios.
Después de varias pruebas descubrí que al modificar los triggers de mi tabla en cuestión agregándole la clausula:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Me guarda los cambios sin problemas, solo que tengo muchos triggers y me seria muy difícil agregar a todos esa modificación.

La cuestión es: habría otra forma de me pueda aplicar los cambios el FireDAC sin tener que agregar dicho código a todos los triggers?

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es posible, de acuerdo a la [documentación](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Update_Command_Generation_(FireDAC)) de la generación de comandos, puedes establecer la propiedad `UpdateOptions.CountUpdatedRecords` a `False`.

Sin embargo, no recomiendo esto como solución final, pues estás forzando al motor a **no validar** que se haya modificado la cantidad exacta de registros que se espera que se modifiquen, lo cual, si el diseño de la tabla no es lo suficientemente bueno o la concurrencia es muy alta, puede dar lugar a otros problemas.

Por ello, mi recomendación, aunque te resulte tedioso, es poner a todos los *triggers* un `set nocount on` al inicio y su correspondiente `set nocount off` al final.

Si los triggers son muchos, incluso, puedes automatizar esta tarea.